# Can one get output from multiple (copy/copyIndex) ARM child Templates?

Tags: azure-rm-template

I have a parent template that takes an array (`websites`) and invokes a childTemplate (`website`) multiple times using the `copyIndex()` method to loop through values in the array passed as a parameter.

Each of the child templates returns -- in its `output`s -- the MSI `principalId`, as well as `outgoingIPAddresses`.

Is there a way one can assemble the returned individual `principalId` values into an array that can be used by subsequent child template invoked by the parent template (in order to loop through the resulting array of `principalId`s and give them all the same rights to a `KeyVault`)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done, although, not as pretty\easy as you would like it to.

easiest way to do this, is assemble an array of values you need using output from the templates. you need each your template to take the output from the previous one and concat it with its own output and spit the result as an output. sample code:

```
    {
        "name": "reference0", << this one is needed so that the first real one has something to reference, as it cant reference itself
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "yourtemplate",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            }
        },
        "parameters": {
            "state": {
                "value": []
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "[concat('reference', copyIndex(1))]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
        "copy": {
            "name": "loop",
            "count": "[variables('types')[resourceGroup().name]]"
        },
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "yourtemplate",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            },
            "parameters": {
                "state": {
                    "value": "[reference(concat('loop', copyIndex())).outputs.state.value]"
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

and your state output should just be something like this:

```
"outputs": {
    "state": {
        "type": "array",
        "value": "[concat(parameters('state'), array(your_actual_output))]"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated: will get me out of a right pickly. PS: at this point, I've noticed its par for the course -- *nothing* is easy/pretty in ARM :-)

Comment: well, i wouldnt go that far, but certainly for anything remotely complex\flexible i tend to fight the syntax\work around weird behaviours mostly (oh and brackets)

Comment: I'm ok with the brackets (ex-Lisper). It's the trailing non-JSON commas that get me. Anyway. Do you know if the above still works without having applying "mode": "serial", "batchSize": 1 as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple ?

Comment: yes, because they all depend on each other, you dont need to change mode. also,  vsts is (for example) is pretty good with commas. no so good with brackets

Comment: How do you actually reference this elsewhere? Surely the last element in the copy is the one that has the full list of state?

Comment: please raise a question and ping me the question url here, I'm not sure what you are asking exactly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927815/arm-template-how-to-reference-a-copyindex-deployment-output