# Create output in Azure ARM template with CopyIndex()

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I was wondering if it's possible to create a custom output bu using Azure ARM template output section

```
  {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "",
  "apiProfile": "",
  "parameters": {  },
  "variables": {  },
  "functions": [  ],
  "resources": [  ],
  "outputs": {
  "customedata1": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[concat(parameters('NameArray')[copyIndex()],'\"'',', variables('CustomData'),'}')]"
        }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think this is possible, depending on what you want to achieve you can do various things to get the desired result. I dont see a point in this particular example, what are you trying to achieve?

you might be able to do what you are trying to achieve with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253858/can-one-get-output-from-multiple-copy-copyindex-arm-child-templates).

Comment: For Linux VM in Azure, I send base64 of a init script to VM. Somehow it doesn't work in way it should. I was looking for a way to see my output(customdata),  that is going to be send to VM [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-data-and-cloud-init-on-windows-azure/)

Comment: whats the point of that, if you are passing it (so you already know\calculate it in the template) just pass it to output as is. you dont need copyIndex for that. pass any single generated instance